# How can I access SoundCloud-Stream URLs in Python?

Tags: python, api, token, soundcloud, unauthorized

Some time ago I wrote a little tool for a friend of mine. I retrieved all stream-links (like [this](http://media.soundcloud.com/stream/TYhPZbZIfUEJ?stream_token=8Qpvy)) from a soundlist and downloaded all those with a small python script.

Since begin of March, soundcloud must have changed something, and now my cronjob recieves `401 Unauthorized` errors. I've read through the soundcloud API, but that whole `Access Token` does not really fit my needs.

Has anyone of you an idea of easily dealing with this problem? Thanks.

Comment: "Unauthorized" might mean you're not meant to access the streams like that, or you've lost whatever privilege you were using to get those streams.

Comment: Yes, but there are several websites that are obviously able to do that without clientside authorization:
[soundcloud-download.com](http://soundcloud-download.com/)for example

Comment: No ideas? Would be very nice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Makoto said, 401 seems like you have lost priviledges to access through your OAuth token so I would double check to make sure your app is still available and that your tokens are correct. You can check on the [Your Apps Page.](http://soundcloud.com/you/apps)

Also, I noticed that your url seemed a bit different than what the SC api shows. Once you resolve to get a proper track id, the convention for a stream url is:

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/{id}/stream
```

This can be found in their [track documentation](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks).

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation [here](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks). You have to add your client_id parameter to the stream url and then you will be redirected to the stream link (mp3).